# C Code-If Conditions HW

Tags: c

I have this code and I always get a segmentation error and i can't run it properly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int num;

    printf("enter the number of words\n");
    scanf("%d", num);

    if (num > 10) {
        printf("a very smart parrot");
    }

    if (num >= 6 && num <= 10) {
        printf ("a smart parrot");
    }

    if (num > 1 && num <= 5) {
        printf ("an average parrot");
    }

    if (num == 0) {
        printf ("a silent parrot");
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf ("%d", &num);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is probably breaking at line `scanf ("%d", num);`

You have to write

```
scanf ("%d", &num);
```

Because function scanf requires pointer as parameter, you have to point to address of `num` to save the read value into the variable

Comment: shame - read the @Eugene Sh. comment. He has answered this question there

Comment: sadly I accidentally sent the answer before I finished writing it @PeterJ_01

Comment: ok accidentally :). But my comment is about something else

Comment: @PeterJ_01 It's OK to have an answer saying the same as a comment, if it is actually an answer. I didn't make it an answer as voted to close immediately. But if it won't get closed - it deserves an official answer.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. I have voted as well. the `scanf` comes back here 10 times a day

Comment: thanks guys...i can't belive i missed something that obvious...:X